# angular 2 router change url without reload

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I translate google sign in javascript to typescript, and it works, the issue.

I'm having is when I call _router variable inside the google sign in function `attachSignin()` the browser url changes correctly but does not redirect the page it just stays there and gives no error.

I already try to add zones but nothin happen just the same here is the code

this is my code

```
import {Component, NgZone} from "angular2/core";
import {ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
import {Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'

// Google's login API namespace
declare var gapi: any;

@Component({
    selector: "sous-app",
    templateUrl: "app/login/login.html",
    providers: [ToastsManager, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class Login {
    googleLoginButtonId = "google-login-button";
    userAuthToken = null;
    userDisplayName = "empty";
    auth2 = null;
    self = this;


        zoneImpl: NgZone;

constructor(zone: NgZone, private _router: Router) {
    this.zoneImpl = zone;
}

    // Angular hook that allows for interaction with elements inserted by the
    // rendering of a view.
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var loginProxy = $.proxy(this.attachSignin, this);
        var redirectToPolls = $.proxy(this.redirectToPolls, this);
        gapi.load('auth2', function () {
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            self.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '718161509287-jdpqsuebcoteh847krjn0m1odnbo5i3q.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                //scope: 'additional_scope'
            });
            loginProxy(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
        });

    }


    attachSignin = (element) => {

        var navigate = false;
        console.log(element.id);
        self.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
            (googleUser) => { {

                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

                //HERE I WANT TO REDIRECT ROUTER
                this.zoneImpl.run(() => this._router.navigate(['Polls']));



                console.log(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);



            }, function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you "provide" `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` anywhere else? other than in the `Login` component, perhaps in `bootstrap(...[ROUTER_PROVIDERS])` ? because you can provide it only once across the whole app. If you provide it multiple times, you will see strange behavior in routing without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect this to throw

```
this.zoneImpl.run(() => this._router.navigate(['Polls']));
```

If you change all

```
function ()
```

to

```
() =>
```

and use `this` instead of `self` and get rid of `self` entirely it should work.